# How do I use file.path() on a list of subdirectories

Tags: r

I want to add "_quants" to a list of folder names contained in samples$sample.  When I use the following:

```
files <- file.path(dir, "quants", samples$sample, "_quants")

> dir
[1] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/"
> samples$sample

 [1] DRR016125 DRR016126 DRR016127 DRR016128 DRR016129 DRR016130 DRR016131 DRR016132 DRR016133 DRR016134 DRR016135 DRR016136 DRR016137 DRR016138 DRR016139
[16] DRR016140
16 Levels: DRR016125 DRR016126 DRR016127 DRR016128 DRR016129 DRR016130 DRR016131 DRR016132 DRR016133 DRR016134 DRR016135 DRR016136 DRR016137 ... DRR016140
```

I get:

```
[1] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial//quants/DRR016125/_quants"
```

How do I remove the double // and append "_quants" to "DRR016125" using file.path() to get the desired:

```
[1] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/quants/DRR016125_quants"
[2] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/quants/DRR016126_quants"
```

Comment: To remove the double `/`, don't include a trailing `/` in your initial object, `dir`. With that, you can do `file.path(dir, "quants", paste0(samples$sample, "_quants"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using [`base::paste0`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/paste):**

```
dir <- "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/"
samples <- list(sample = c("DRR016125", "DRR016126", "DRR016127"))

paste0(dir, "quants", samples$sample, "_quants")
[1] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/quantsDRR016125_quants"
[2] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/quantsDRR016126_quants"
[3] "E:/ubuntu-shared/salmonTutorial/quantsDRR016127_quants"
```

`paste0` - concatenates vectors (after converting to character), i.e. outputs single string. And as you passed multiple `samples` it does this for every sample.

Comment: Better to point to the user's local documentation with `?paste0`.